# insert or update(upsert) in loopback application

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, upsert

I developed an API using Loopback framework, in that i have to `insert or update` to a table.

My table looks like below:

```
userid  bbid saved  id(PK)
  1      5    1000   1
```

So when next time if(bbid = 5) it should update the above row, if bbid =5 is not there it should insert into the above table.

I tried the following:

```
app.models.modelname.upsert({
  bbid: bb.id,
  saved: Saved,
  userid: 1
}, function(err, res) {});
```

EDIT for COMPOSITE ID:

```
app.models.modelname.upsert({
  bbid: vvvv.bbid,
  userid: 1,
  saved: amountSaved
}, function(err, res) {});
```

Also gone through Loopback doc it says

```
    upsert - checks if the instance (record) exists, based on the designated 
ID property, which must have a unique value; if the instance already exists, 
the method updates that instance.  Otherwise, it inserts a new instance.
```

But in my case it should check for `bbid not id`

But its inserting everytime. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance

EDIT FOR UPSERT:

My process is as follows:

```
Fetch from table1 and loop that response and calculate the saved and upsert it into another table(table2 (this is where upsert should happen)). Also the fetching from table1 will happen frequently so suppose consider if is happens 2nd time it should update the already present bbid..
```

Comment: There is no way to use upsert with another key. It should be model key defined in mode.json. So you should fetch it and update/insert. There is extended key in loopback, but I think it doesn't work for upsert

Comment: For last try yes. Please check this out https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-CompositeIDs. Define composite id for your model and upsert might work with that

Comment: did you try composite id?

Comment: For example : `"id": {
    "type": "string", 
    "id": true 
   },"bbid": {
    "type": "string", 
    "id": true 
   }`

Comment: Did you put `id` in your data sent to `upsert`?

Comment: @Ebrahim Pasbani I have edited the post what i tried?? Whether i have to give id or bbid in upsert statement.. Can you please provide the syntax for upsert.. Also id is auto-generated how can i give that in my upsert??

Comment: If you don't have id  how `upsert` should know insert or update?? So you should have `id` to do that. To clarify, where  you call upsert?

Comment: @Ebrahim Pasbani I edited the post. If needed i am ready to give more info..

Comment: `app.models.modelname.upsert({bbid:bb.id, saved: Saved, userid:1}
              ,function(err, res){
});` here you should provide `id`. If not, so `upsert` doesn't find `id` and calls insert. Maybe you should think about what is(are) id's in that model. What key(s) do you want for that model?

Comment: @Ebrahim Pasbani As i already said id is auto-generated i cant give manually right?? Otherwise can i have only bbid in that table which is primary key..

Comment: Yes, you can. In model.json you need to ignore `id` and set `bbid` as id of the model. `"properties": {
    "id": false,
    "bbid": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    }`

Comment: @Ebrahim Pasbani  `conradj` solution is working.. Thanks for your valuable time..

Comment: working but not fit to your question. You wanted upsert not finding

Comment: @Ebrahim Pasbani  yes its workaround,but no other way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`findOrCreate`](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findorcreate) method as follows:

```
app.models.modelname({where: {bbid:bb.id} }, {bbid:bb.id, saved: Saved, userid:1}, function(err, instance) {
    if (err){
        cb(null, err);
    }
        cb(null, instance);  
    });
```

Comment: @conradj Will this update the instance if found? Or does it just find the instance?

Comment: @DevStar use `upsertWithWhere` if you want to do that http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-upsert

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods in loopback one is simple upsert and second is upsertWithWhere.To insert or update based on where condition you must use upsertWithWhere method upsert only inserts the data.
you are using

```
app.models.modelname.upsert({bbid:bb.id, saved: Saved, userid:1}
          ,function(err, res){});
```

instead use

```
app.models.modelname.upsertWithWhere({bbid:bb.id, saved: Saved, userid:1}
          ,function(err, res){});
```

this will solve your problem.

note: this only updates single instance.If multiple instances are returned in where condition result it will throw an error.